# Why send message in diffrent time but receive mssage in the same time when use zmq delear/delear model

Tags: python, pyzmq

When I use *DEALER-DEALER* model to communicate, I find: server send messages in different time, but client receive messages in the same. For example (Python code):

```
# server
context = zmq.Context()
sock_conn = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
sock_conn.bind("tcp://*:%d" % port)
sock_conn.send("msg1")
time.sleep(0.05)
sock_conn.send("msg2")

# client
context_send = zmq.Context()
sock_send = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
sock_send.connect("tcp://%s:%d" % (ip, port1))
while True:
    msg = sock_send.recv()
    print(msg)
```

The server sends the message in different time, but sometimes the client receives the messages at the same time, who can explain this problem, thanks.

Comment: why your ports not same with togeather?

Comment: The server is running  on a machine, and the client running on another machine, so the port variable can not be same. I apologise if my code has any influence on your comprehension.